# Python Twisted framework HTTP client

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I want to write a simple SSL HTTP client in Python and have heard about the Twisted framework.

I need to be able to authenticate with a REST service - so I was thinking I'd just POST a user name and password to the target server. Assuming authentication is successful, the client will receive a cookie.

Will an HTTP client built on Twisted automatically resend the cookie header for each subsequent request, or do I need to do something special? I've never used Twisted before.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will an HTTP client built on Twisted automatically resend the cookie header for each subsequent request, or do I need to do something special?

"an HTTP client built on Twisted" will do anything it is built to do - just like, presumably any X built on any Y will do whatever it was built to do. :)  So I might suggest that this isn't the question you really care about the answer to.

Since Twisted 11.1.0, [twisted.web.client.CookieAgent](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.CookieAgent.html) accepts a `cookieJar` argument which does two things:

- it defines the cookies which are available to be sent with the requests
- it stores new cookies received from servers in responses

The soon-to-be-deprecated [twisted.web.client.getPage](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.client.getPage.html) accepts a `cookies` argument behaves similarly.

So if you use `CookieAgent` then the cookie will be persisted and sent with subsequent requests, providing the authentication behavior you're after.

You could also do something with `getPage` but given its impending doom you probably shouldn't.